# Connect to SQL Server 2005 with trusted connection and username

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, oledbconnection

I want to connect to **MS SQL Server 2005** in my **C#** application.
The **SQL server** is running on a remote machine.

I want to connect to the **SQL server** by using trusted connection (=a requirement by the customer). But the problem is that the user running the **C#** application is not the same as the one on the remote machine which is hosting the **SQL server**.

is it possible to specify the connection string in a way to give the Windows user name that I want to use to connect to the **SQL server** in my application?

Or in other words: Is it possible to use something like:

```
connString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDB; uid=MyWindowsTargetUser;"
```

Comment: Trusted Connection is a synonym for `Windows Authentication. You don't need a username. What application is this? Desktop? Web? Just add the user or the user's group as a login to SQL Server. Windows Authentication is a *lot* easier to manage and secure than having individual SQL Server logins, or one login used by every user

Comment: It is a desktop application. So you are recommending to add the application's user to the SQL Server logins? Unfortunately, the user isn't existing in Windows on the target machine. And the customer doesn't want to modify the system to create this user.

Comment: Why do you want to provide a username in this case? The server already knows who the end user is.

Comment: I'm not recommending anything since you haven't provided essential details. It does sound though as there's a lack of understanding of how Windows works. In a domain, servers know who the user is. If anyone asks about Trusted Connections ie Windows Authentication that's what they mean. There's no `modify the system to create this user`. You add the original user as a login to SQL Server. Better yet, you put the application's users in a group and add the *group*

Comment: I suspect there's no domain though, but two Workgroup computers and the customer doesn't really understand what Windows Authentication means in this environment. If one ComputerA\UserA wants to access resources, eg files  on ComputerB, the same username and password *must* exist there. The same holds for SQL Server access

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will suggest to put the user in a group which already has access rights on the SQL Server